# Arrow key input code not working in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

The following is my short script. It is meant to print right left and up when those arrow keys are held, but I don't know why it does not work.

```
import Tkinter as tk

right = False
left = False
up = False

def keyPressed(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Escape':
        root.destroy()
    if event.keysym == 'Right':
        right = True
    if event.keysym == 'Left':
        left = True
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        up = True

def keyReleased(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Right':
        right = False
    if event.keysym == 'Left':
        left = False
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        up = False

def task():
    if right:
        print 'Right'
    if left:
        print 'Left'
    if up:
        print 'Forward'
    root.after(20,task)

root = tk.Tk()
print( "Press arrow key (Escape key to exit):" )

root.bind_all('<Key>', keyPressed)
root.bind_all('<KeyRelease>', keyReleased)
root.after(20,task)

root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```

The issue began when I started using `root.after()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In python, functions create a new scope.  If a variable isn't found within the function's scope, python looks in the outer (module/file) scope for the variable.  You add variables into the current scope with assignment.  This all means that:

```
right = False
def func():
    right = True
func()
print (right)  #right is still False in the outer scope.
```

In order to actually modify the variable in an outer scope, you need to tell python that you want to do something like that *explicitly*:

```
right = False
def func():
    global right
    right = True
func()
print (right)
```

This works, but it's not considered good practice because you're changing the state of your program.  Now the value of `right` depends on whether you've called a function which is a bit unsettling.

A better way to share data between function calls is to use a **class**.  Then methods (functions bound to an instance of the class) can change the state of that single instance, but the rest of your program can continue as if nothing happened.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.right = False
    def func(self):
        self.right = True

a = Foo() #calls __init__ implicitly
print(a.right)  #should be False -- We set this in __init__
a.func()  #change state of `a`
print(a.right)  #Now it's True!
```

Here's a slightly more "classy" version of your code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.right = False
        self.left = False
        self.up = False

    def keyPressed(self,event):
        print "HERE"
        if event.keysym == 'Escape':
            root.destroy()
        elif event.keysym == 'Right':
            self.right = True
        elif event.keysym == 'Left':
            self.left = True
        elif event.keysym == 'Up':
            self.up = True

    def keyReleased(self,event):
        if event.keysym == 'Right':
            self.right = False
        elif event.keysym == 'Left':
            self.left = False
        elif event.keysym == 'Up':
            self.up = False

    def task(self):
        if self.right:
            print 'Right'
        elif self.left:
            print 'Left'
        elif self.up:
            print 'Forward'
        root.after(20,self.task)

application = App()
root = tk.Tk()
print( "Press arrow key (Escape key to exit):" )

root.bind_all('<Key>', application.keyPressed)
root.bind_all('<KeyRelease>', application.keyReleased)
root.after(20,application.task)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As a side note, I had to remove the `root.withdrawl()` so that I still had a window to send keyboard commands to...

Comment: @SmileyJames -- No problem.  Happy to lend assistance :)

Comment: absolutely awesome :D