# input() :: Using Backspace And Arrow Keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script that takes information from the user through the built in input() function.

My question is why do the backspace and arrow keys not function correctly and how can I fix it so they function as intended.

A simple example of the problem I am having...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
while 1:
  x=input("enter integer: ")
  y=int(x)*17
  print(y)
```

Here is an example of using it.

```
./tester 
enter integer: 3
51
enter integer: 17
289
enter integer: 172^[[D^[[D^H
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tester", line 4, in <module>
    y=int(x)*17
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '172\x08'
```

In trying to remove the '1' using the arrow keys and backspace, ^[[D^[[D^H came up instead of deleting moving left two spaces and removing the '1', and the value crashed the program.

How do I fix this so all of the keys function as intended?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Import the `readline` module from the standard library.
It automatically wraps stdin.

For example:

```py
import readline

while True:
    response = input("> ").strip()

    if response.lower() == "quit":
        break

    print(f"You entered '{response}'")
```

Comment: This answer would be substantially better with a code example

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Simply adding "import readline" before calling input() changed its behavior to allow back and front arrows, delete, backspace, home and end to work. Also up and down arrows recall history.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the tkinter library:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter

There's also a good discussion of the library here on SO:

[Arrow key input code not working in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595284/python-tkinter-arrow-key-input-code-not-functioning)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that thread.  I was turned off by the GUI.  I just want to be able to use the backspace in the input() in my terminal.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer from @t-8ch, here is an illustrative example:

```
import sys
print("Enter choice(1-4):")

res = sys.stdin.readline()  # used in place of input()
# to strip the new line from stdin like '4\n' and then convert str to int
ch = int(res.strip())
```

Comment: This is helpful, but the `readline` module in t-8ch's answer is different than the `sys.stdin.readline()` method.