# Using backspace to clear input when running a program with subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, subprocess, user-input

I am currently trying to run a C program from python by using the `subprocess.Popen` method. Running a regular program is working fine. But when I run a program that requires an input, the input can be typed, but when I try to clear the input using backspace, it doesn't do anything. Also after pressing backspace, no more input can be typed. Similarly, the arrow keys don't position the cursor in the input.

The behavior seems to be similar to the default behavior of the python `input()` method. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14796424) shows that this can be fixed by importing the `readline` module. I have tried this, and it does work for `input()`, but backspace and arrow keys still don't work when reading input from a subprocess.

This is the python program I am using:

```
import subprocess
import os
import readline
c1 = subprocess.Popen(["gcc -Ofast program.c"], shell=True).wait()
if not c1:
    c2 = subprocess.Popen("./a.out", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, env=os.environ.copy()).wait()
```

The program being compiled and run is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
        int a, b;
        printf("Enter a: ");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        printf("Enter b: \n");
        scanf("%d", &b);
        
        printf("a + b = %d", a+b);

        return 0;
}
```

Is there some way to change the terminal behavior for a python subprocess with input so that backspace and arrow keys can work as in a normal shell?